R: Reduce space between columns in legend
I use the following R command to create a legend for my plot:
legend("topright",
             legend = c("", "T = 500", "T = 1000", "T = 2000",
                        expression(lambda[1]), format(eigenvalues[1, 1], digits = 3),
                        format(eigenvalues[2, 1], digits = 3), format(eigenvalues[3, 1], digits = 3),
                        expression(lambda[2]), format(eigenvalues[1, 2], digits = 3),
                        format(eigenvalues[2, 2], digits = 3), format(eigenvalues[3, 2], digits = 3)),
             lty = c(0, 1, 1, 1, rep(0, 8)),  # Segments only for T rows
             col = c("", "blue", "red", "gray30", rep("", 8)),
             seg.len = c(0, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, rep(0, 8)),  # 0 seg.len for lambdas
             ncol = 3, bty = "o", title = "")

The whole script is too long to be put here. The resulting legend is shown below:

Now the problem as you can see is that there is too much space between columns, which causes the legend to sometimes cover the plot. How to reduce the space between columns?
EDIT:
I tried the first answer:
legend("topright" ,
             legend = c("", "T = 500", "T = 1000", "T = 2000",
                        expression(lambda[1]), format(eigenvalues[1, 1], digits = 3),
                        format(eigenvalues[2, 1], digits = 3), format(eigenvalues[3, 1], digits = 3),
                        expression(lambda[2]), format(eigenvalues[1, 2], digits = 3),
                        format(eigenvalues[2, 2], digits = 3), format(eigenvalues[3, 2], digits = 3)),
             lty = c(0, 1, 1, 1, rep(0, 8)),  # Segments only for T rows
             col = c("", "blue", "red", "gray30", rep("", 8)),
             seg.len = c(0, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, rep(0, 8)),  # 0 seg.len for lambdas
             ncol = 3, bty = "o", title = "",
             text.width = Xs)

But now the elements in the legend are overlapping:


You can pass a vector of column widths in the legend using the text.width parameter of legend(). Give text.width one value for each column. I made a simple plot with and added your legend, which has three columns. Compare the two plots below. The first uses the default text.width and the second uses values I passed in. The widths are in the units of the x axis.
eigenvalues <- matrix(c(1:6), nrow = 3)
plot(1:3, 1:3)
legend("topright" ,
       legend = c("", "T = 500", "T = 1000", "T = 2000",
                  expression(lambda[1]), format(eigenvalues[1, 1], digits = 3),
                  format(eigenvalues[2, 1], digits = 3), format(eigenvalues[3, 1], digits = 3),
                  expression(lambda[2]), format(eigenvalues[1, 2], digits = 3),
                  format(eigenvalues[2, 2], digits = 3), format(eigenvalues[3, 2], digits = 3)),
       lty = c(0, 1, 1, 1, rep(0, 8)),  # Segments only for T rows
       col = c("", "blue", "red", "gray30", rep("", 8)),
       seg.len = c(0, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, rep(0, 8)),  # 0 seg.len for lambdas
       ncol = 3, bty = "o", title = "")




Xs <- c(0.25,0.1,0.1)  #vector of column widths in the legend
plot(1:3, 1:3)
legend("topright" ,
       legend = c("", "T = 500", "T = 1000", "T = 2000",
                  expression(lambda[1]), format(eigenvalues[1, 1], digits = 3),
                  format(eigenvalues[2, 1], digits = 3), format(eigenvalues[3, 1], digits = 3),
                  expression(lambda[2]), format(eigenvalues[1, 2], digits = 3),
                  format(eigenvalues[2, 2], digits = 3), format(eigenvalues[3, 2], digits = 3)),
       lty = c(0, 1, 1, 1, rep(0, 8)),  # Segments only for T rows
       col = c("", "blue", "red", "gray30", rep("", 8)),
       seg.len = c(0, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, rep(0, 8)),  # 0 seg.len for lambdas
       ncol = 3, bty = "o", title = "",
       text.width = Xs)


Created on 2024-11-09 with reprex v2.1.1

Thank you for the answer, I tried it but now the elements of the legend are overlapping. See my edit.

What are the values in Xs? In my example, the x axis spans 3 units, but in yours it spans about 30 units. I expect your widths will have to be larger than mine.

Text may shift during resizing in RStudio preview; use a device for stable display.
